# Add user with card numer to ZKTime Device

Tags: python, time-and-attendance

I'm using Python 2.7, and I use PyZk to communicate with ZKTime (Time Attendence software) on Linux OS, And I can't set user with '**Card Number**'. Below the method that allows to add a user in the device, how can I add the card number for user?

```
set_user(uid=1, name='Fanani M. Ihsan', privilege=const.USER_ADMIN, password='12345678', group_id='', user_id='123')
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new version can do that

https://github.com/fananimi/pyzk

```
set_user(uid=345, name='', privilege=0, password='', group_id='', user_id='123', card=0)
```

This response for everyone search for the solution